# Show different default page depending on stored value

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

I am trying to make an windows store app where the default page (first page that comes up when app loads) changes depending on stored value.

I have following files

```
- js
   |- default.js
- default.html
- page_A.html
- page_B.html
```

`default.js` has the following code:

```
if (localStorage["value"] == undefined || localStorage["value"] == "pageA") {
    localStorage["value"] = "pageA";
    //WinJS.Navigation.navigate("page_A.html");
    window.location.assign = "page_A.html";
} else {
    localStorage["value"] = "pageB";
    //WinJS.Navigation.navigate("page_B.html");
    window.location.assign = "page_B.html";
}
```

`WinJS.Navigation` code does not work at all. So I tried using `window.location` and what's happening is instead of loading the actual page, it loads an empty page as shown below.

I tried using both `href` and `assign` for `windows.location` object. What's interesting is that it **seems** like `href` and `assign` loads the page because if I have `page_A/B.js` associated with `pageA/B.html` and have a simple `console.log` statement, then the log statement does get logged, but it does not render the page.

Any ideas? I've been stuck for a while.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `default.js` at the root of your project, next to `page_A.html` and `page_B.html`, or, and I don't know if this works, you can try calling those pages with `..\page_X.html`.

Also, you can add an error handler function to your navigate in case there's something else going on that you're not seeing.

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate('page_A.html', {}).then(function () {
    // it worked!
}, function (err){
    // something went wrong
});
```

Comment: Provided solution did not work. It's funny that the navigation calls the function in "it worked" part but the current page is still the default page not the "page_A.html".